# List azure ad users using java

Tags: java, azure, sdk, azure-active-directory

What is the way to connect to azure ad with username and password using java
I use python to print all users of azure directory but couldn't find a way to connect using username and password in java...

```
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials 
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

credentials = UserPassCredentials("username", "password", resource="https://graph.windows.net")

tenant_id = 'tenant id'
graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials,tenant_id)
users = graphrbac_client.users.list()
for user in users:
    print(f"Display name={user.display_name}UserPrincipleName={user.user_principal_name}")
```

the task is to print all users in the directory by making connection with username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Microsoft Graph** supports all functionality exposed by Azure AD Graph, and Microsoft Graph is recommended.

**Install the dependency via Gradle**:

Add the repository and a compile dependency for microsoft-graph-auth to your project's build.gradle

```
repository {
    jcenter()
    jcenter{
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
    }
}

dependency {
    // Include the sdk as a dependency
    compile('com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph-auth:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT')
}
```

Here is a working sample for your reference:

```
public static void main(String [] rags){
        UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider("{client_id}", Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All") , "{username}", "{password}", NationalCloud.Global, "{tenant}", "{cient_secret}");
        IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .buildClient();
        IUserCollectionPage userCollectionPage = graphClient.users().buildRequest().get();
        List<User> userList=userCollectionPage.getCurrentPage();
    }
```

**Note:** Remember to add the Microsoft graph api permission int the portal and grant admin consent.

[image]

**Reference:**

[msgraph-sdk-java-auth](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth)

Answer (score 0):

I am receiving the following error message, when I apply the solution proposed above. any idea why the error happens??
I am using this version of library -> com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph-auth:0.3.0

com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.7.1
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]